# How to get an artifact generated from a container?

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild

I have a Dockerfile dedicated to run my unit test, but i am not sure how i am supposed to get the coverage directory it generates (inside the container).
I would like to be able to get it as an artifact to be able to analyze it, but is it possible since it is generated from the container?

Answer (score 2):

Use **docker cp** command

If you want to copy the /tmp/foo directory from a container to the existing /tmp directory on your host. If you run docker cp in your ~ (home) directory on the local host:

```
$ docker cp container_name:tmp/foo /tmp
```

Docker creates a /tmp/foo directory on your host.

If your container dies after executing you can map a volume from you host to the container, in this way you will have your data in your host after the container dies.

```
VOLUME ["/home/data"]
```

This will map /home/data in your machine with /home/data in your container, adjust at will.

More info
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about that, it could be useful in some cases but in the case of unit tests, the container dies after the test is done. Is there another way ?

Comment: Edited my answer.